# `M-x` compile always runs the same command

Tags: c++

I'm a very new user (~ 2 days) to Emacs. I switched from vim, because it wasn't working for me. I'm learning C++ and I've run into this issue when I write `M-x compile`. Upon writing this command, emacs always runs `make -k` on my small test program. However, I want it that emacs asks me what command to run for instance, in this example I want to run `g++ program_ name -o output_name`. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Ask Emacs.**

`C-h f compile` tells you:

> Compile the program including the current buffer.  Default: run `make`.
>   Runs COMMAND, a shell command, in a separate process asynchronously
>   with output going to the buffer `*compilation*`.
>
> You can then use the command `` C-x ` `` to find the next error message
>   and move to the source code that caused it.
>
> If optional second arg COMINT is t the buffer will be in Comint mode with
>   `compilation-shell-minor-mode`.
>
> **Interactively, prompts for the command if the variable
>   `compilation-read-command` is non-nil**; otherwise uses `compile-command`.
>   With prefix arg, always prompts.
>   Additionally, with universal prefix arg, compilation buffer will be in
>   comint mode, i.e. interactive.
>
> To run more than one compilation at once, start one then rename
>   the `*compilation*` buffer to some other name with
>   M-x rename-buffer.  Then *switch buffers* and start the new compilation.
>   It will create a new `*compilation*` buffer.
>
> On most systems, termination of the main compilation process
>   kills its subprocesses.
>
> The name used for the buffer is actually whatever is returned by
>   the function in `compilation-buffer-name-function`, so you can set that
>   to a function that generates a unique name.

The part in **bold** tells you the answer: be sure that user option **`compilation-read-command`** is set to a non-`nil` value.

And if you click the `compilation-read-command` link in that `*Help*` output then you get even more information about its behavior:

> Non-nil means M-x compile reads the compilation command to use.
>   Otherwise, M-x compile just uses the value of `compile-command`.
>
> Note that changing this to nil may be a security risk, because a
>   file might define a malicious `compile-command` as a file local
>   variable, and you might not notice.  Therefore, `compile-command`
>   is considered unsafe if this variable is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a prompt by default, unless you've set `compilation-read-command` to `nil` in your config.

What I always do is write a Makefile and use [helm-make](https://github.com/abo-abo/helm-make) instead of `compile`.

Comment: Hey thanks, I used helm but then ended it removing it from my .emacs since it was getting more obstructive. Also do you write a Makefile for every C++ program you write?

Comment: Yes, every C++ program. They can be autogenerated, see `ccc-run` https://github.com/abo-abo/cc-chainsaw/blob/master/cc-chainsaw.el#L303

Comment: Hey I just went to the link, understanding it will require me to know more elisp. Can you tell me how to actually be more productive in elisp?

Comment: Go through the tutorial. Use `M-x` to access all built-in stuff, and `eval-buffer` to try new stuff.
You won't learn it all in a day, but after some time investment it's really worth. Also have a look at SICP if you don't know any other LISP.

Comment: Oh yes I have worked through sicp, hence it was easy to write my .emacs. I'll just add your package to my emacs